# YuiDocs external data link usage

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, yuidoc

I have an ember-cli project that needs documentation, I am using the [ember-cli-yuidoc](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-cli-yuidoc) plugin and this is my `yuidoc.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "Small description for myapp goes here",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "options": {
    "paths": [
      "app"
    ],
    "exclude": "vendor",
    "outdir": "docs"
  },
  "external": {
    "data": [
      {
        "base": "http://emberjs.com/api/",
        "json": "http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.8.1/ember-docs.json"
      },
      {
        "base": "http://emberjs.com/api/",
        "json": "http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/beta/daily/20130929/ember-data-docs.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to link in my `login.js` route to `Ember.Route` (it extends it).

```
/**
 * @module route
 * @extends Ember.Route
 * @class  login
 */
```

The generated docs look like this:
[image: login class docs]

The above fails to link to the proper object, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in ember-cli-yuidoc@0.5.4, please try it.

- https://github.com/cibernox/ember-cli-yuidoc/pull/13
- https://github.com/cibernox/ember-cli-yuidoc/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md